# HSQLDB batch delete failed but in Oracle it works

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, hsqldb

I have a setup with : Spring+Hibernate+JPA+Junit to test my code.

I have Oracle as database.  When I test my code every test passed.  This code is even in production.I wanted to use HSQLDB in memory for the junit instead of Oracle.Most of the tests still passed with HSQLDB, but one particular test always fail with HQSQLDB. (Works fin in Oracle).

here the line that cause trouble.  (I used log4jdbc to output the sql statements).

creating batch for two statements:

> 1: delete from IMAGE_TAGS where IMAGE_TAGS_KEY=1
>
> 2: delete from IMAGE_TAGS where IMAGE_TAGS_KEY=2

in JPA, I'm looking on entity to delete them.  Works fine on the first iteration, but when I arrive to the second item, it fail with this exception :

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatcher.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2666)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2911)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1185)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1283)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:117)
    at com.videotron.imagemanager.dao.ImageContentGroupDAOImpl.removeImageContentGroup(ImageContentGroupDAOImpl.java:143)
    at com.videotron.imagemanager.dao.ImageContentGroupDAOImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$8ef3e206.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:627)
    at com.videotron.imagemanager.dao.ImageContentGroupDAOImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a153b522.removeImageContentGroup(<generated>)
    at com.videotron.imagemanager.service.ImageManagerServiceImpl.cleanContent(ImageManagerServiceImpl.java:270)
    at com.videotron.imagemanager.service.ImageManagerServiceImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$82a03251.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:627)
    at com.videotron.imagemanager.service.ImageManagerServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1a5a3f0d.cleanContent(<generated>)
    at com.videotron.imagemanager.image.impl.v1.ImageManagerImpl.cleanContent(ImageManagerImpl.java:1454)
    at com.videotron.imagemanager.image.impl.v1.ImageManagerImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$4ded3863.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.videotron.imagemanager.image.impl.v1.ImageManagerImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c6ce4df.cleanContent(<generated>)
    at com.videotron.imagemanager.service.ImageManagerServiceFacade.cleanContent(ImageManagerServiceFacade.java:350)
    at com.videotron.imagemanager.service.ImageManagerServiceFacade$$FastClassByCGLIB$$558f388b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:627)
    at com.videotron.imagemanager.service.ImageManagerServiceFacade$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$fb734807.cleanContent(<generated>)
    at com.videotron.imagemanager.service.ImageManagerServiceFacadeTest.testCleanContent(ImageManagerServiceFacadeTest.java:671)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause of exception `org.hibernate.StaleStateException` is mainly because of

> "Hibernate caches objects from the session. If the object was
>   modified, and Hibernate doesn’t know about it, it will throw this
>   exception".

Or

> Flushing the data before committing the object may lead to clear all
>   object pending for persist.

I will suggest set log level of spring and log4jdbc to `debug` and enable `show_sql` of hibernate this willl gives you clear idea.

**Update**

As on first look i Think that:

On First iteration when you say Delete `IMAGE_TAGS_KEY` 1 and 2 hibernate fires this query so that you are getting this query logged by log4jdbc but still transaction is not commited so the changes is still not written in DB and on second iteration again you are deleting the same keys which is pending to get reflected.

Comment: that's the behavior that I though happened.  Just not sure why It works fine on Oracle but not with HSQLDB.   I'll rewrite the queries and test it again.